# UITabbarController with nonselected index

Tags: iphone

i created a sample tabbar application with 4 tabs.When i run the application the default selected tabbarcontroller index is 0.
So when i change this to

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;
```

Its loaded the third tabbaritem and its viewcontroller.

What i want is , when i added tabbarcontroller.view to window i want to show a non selected index of tabitem in tabbarcontroller.In that i want to show a temp loading image. After that they clicked the tabbaritem it loaded its view controller.

Can anyone help me? This is possible ? I think its quite diffcult to me....

Note(Mainly i want to show all tabbaritem with non selected index).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, when you set SelectedIndex to 2, you get the third tab because the array is zero based (like all arrays in Objective-C).  So, the indexes are: 0 => first, 1 => second, 2 => third

I'm not sure what you really want to do.  A tabBar cannot have nothing selected, then there would be nothing to display.  If you want a temp loading image while the application starts up, look at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) and look for 'launch images'.

If you want to show an image AFTER the application has launched but before they select a tab bar index, then just have one of your viewControllers display an image the first time it's launched.  i.e.

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
```

viewController at index 0 in it's viewWillAppear method just displays and image that says: "Press a button".